# Delete with delimiters, but not whitespace around (vim)

Tags: vim

In situation as below, I want to delete `"TWO"`:

```
foobar("ONE", "TWO");
//              ^-- cursor here
```

so I press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>, and the result is:

```
foobar("ONE",);
//           ^-- cursor here
```

How can I change this not to delete the space near the comma? Or what keys should I use? I never yet found situation where this behavior (of deleting space) would be what I want.

Comment: I don't think that you can change this behavior. What about `F"df"`?

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> (or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>, which is the same). This is a special case of using count with <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> text-object, which removes all text inside quotes including quotes, acting just as you want it.

See also `:help iquote`.

You can find detailed explanation on removing spaces in `:help aquote`. It may not be really useful for something enclosed in quotes, but removing trailing space or leading when there is no trailing space definitely makes sense when you use sentence or paragraph text-objects. The behavior could be made same for all text-object just for consistency.